# compare two values of different type (but identical underlying type)

Tags: go, types, compare

How do I compare the values of two variables that have different types but the same underlying type.

```
type   SomeID    uint8
type   OtherID   uint8

func areEqual(sid SomeID, oid OtherID) bool {
   // error: mismatched types
   return sid == oid
}
```

Comment: First convert them back to `uint8` and then compare those uints.

Comment: Though this does raise the question of why these are different types; the point of creating primitive-based types is usually to distinguish them, meaning that comparing a `SomeID` to a `OtherID` shouldn't yield any meaningful result; like comparing a `time.Month` to a `time.Weekday`, which are both `int` but have different *meaning* and are therefore incomparable.

Comment: exactly - and usually one adds methods to a distinct type which ultimately define its unique characteristics.

Comment: @Adrian I agree, however this was part of an assignment so the problem is rather fabricated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by mkopriva, type-conversion is needed to compare the values.

https://tour.golang.org/basics/13

```
func areEqual(sid SomeID, oid OtherID) bool {
   return uint8(sid) == uint8(oid)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can be less accurate, you don't need to remember underlying type

```
func areEqual(sid SomeID, oid OtherID) bool {
   return sid == SomeID(oid)
}
```

And you can be more generic

```
func areEqual(x, y interface{}) (bool, error) {
    xv := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    yv := reflect.ValueOf(y)
    if yv.Type().ConvertibleTo(xv.Type()) {
        return xv.Interface() == yv.Convert(xv.Type()).Interface(), nil
    } else {
        return false, errors.New("Types are mismatched")
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L6kWlJjV-Ql)